# What will happen if i call one method from AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Suppose there is a method which is used to fetch the data in string by passing url say:

```
public class JsonParser extends AsyncTask<Void,String,JsonObject>{
doInBackground(String url){
..........
.....  }
 postExecute(Jobject jobj){
......
return data;
}
}
```

Now if i call this method from three to four AsyncTasks and passing different urls, is there any possibilty that i may get data mismatch..

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to get mismatched data because Async task work independently of each other i.e doesn't wait for other task to end. 
[Async task details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)